# Clustering similar words and mapping to numbers in Python

Tags: python, mapping-strategy, clustering

I'm familiar with kmeans to cluster data points, but not text.. So I have one column of words in cvs format, which I want to cluster those which have similar word or more, and then mapping those cluster to numbers as index, those index numbers needed to be added as a second column. I know there is scipy packahes and word2vec in python, but this is the first time for me dealing with clustering text.. Any idea on how to do this??

Comment: I think you have it.  the pipeline is cvs -> words -> word2vec -> kmeans -> clusters -> Profit!!